Render Any component inside another component
i need to create view like bottomsheet reusable component in which i can show header part and then inside container div i should be able to load any component [screenshot attached ]

I am unable to load any component inside Bottomsheet Component .
Here is what i have tried .
`bottomsheet-component.html

<p> {{ title }}</p>
<ng-container #container></ng-container>

Component

import { Component,Input, ViewChild,ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-bottomsheet-component',
  templateUrl: './bottomsheet-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bottomsheet-component.css']
})
export class BottomsheetComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() component: any;

  @Input() title: string = 'Default';

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.component) {
      const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
      this.container.clear(); // Clear previous content
      this.container.createComponent(componentFactory); // Create and insert the component
    }else {
      console.log('component is nil inside ngAfterViewInit')
    }
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.component) {
      const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
      this.container.clear(); // Clear previous content
      this.container.createComponent(componentFactory); // Create and insert the component
    }else {
      console.log('component is nil inside ngOnInit')
    }
  }

}

Can't see inside strybook :



const Template: StoryFn = (args) => ({
  props: args,
});


export const Grid= Template.bind({});
Grid = {
   title: “My Component” 
   component: GridComponent
};

export const List= Template.bind({});
List = {
   title: “My user list” 
   component: UserListComponent
};


<ng-container #container></ng-container>`

Please help me to render any component inside bottom sheet .

You can use ion-sheet-modal https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#sheet-modal. and create component. then your can load any component inside your sheet
